# Adding Privacy Policy page into app settings on iOS

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, appsettings

I want to add my Privacy Policy, Terms of Use etc. pages into the app's settings page, which is located in OS's Settings app. (ex: **News** app's settings have a policy page in its own settings ***on iOS 12 Beta***)

I have 2 questions about this approach.

**1. Is it a good approach?** Not only for policy pages, I want to locate every in-app settings in here.
**2. How can I do that?**

Thank you.

EDIT: According to docs I cannot add a controller or an UITextView into App Settings.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Answer (score 1):

There are the answers for your questions.

1. Yes it is a good approach.
2. You can do it by using UIWebView or in UITextView as well.

Comment: Thanks, Bilal, but "how can I do that" meant a bit more; of course I will use UITextView, but this is not the case, the case is, how can I add a controller into settings page.

Comment: According to current docs, I cannot add a controller or a UITextView there: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html